# How to import Sass libraries such as Bourbon or Compass in a Django Project

Tags: python, django, sass

I'm trying to use SASS in a Django project and I've tried configuring it with both Compressor and Django-pipeline but I keep having issues. This error will come up repeatedly, I know it's not a syntax error and rather that my SASS executable can't find the gems for the libraries I've installed. How could I fix this?

Here is the error.

```
/*
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon.
              Load path: /vagrant/projects/wellingtoncordeiro/assets/css (DEPRECATED)
        on line 25 of /vagrant/projects/wellingtoncordeiro/assets/css/main.scss

20: //
21: //    $THIRD-PARTY IMPORTS
22: //
23: 
24: 
25: @import 'bourbon';
26: @import 'compass';
27: @import 'breakpoint';
28: @import 'lib/jeet/index';
```

And here is my [settings](https://gist.github.com/994854ae2ca6439ef4bc) file in the Django project.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't a Rails app you shall import by

```
@import 'bourbon/bourbon';
```